# Converter uma coleção do tipo Set para List

Tags: java, lista, set

Tenho uma classe que possui um atributo do tipo de Set, pois desejo que valores repetidos sejam ignorados, contudo preciso retornar isso em forma de List para preencher em um `ListView`, sendo assim qual a melhor forma de implementar esse recurso?

**Leitor.java**

```
package br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Entity.Patrimonio;
import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.Database.Database;
import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID.DotR900.OnBtEventListener;
import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID.DotR900.R900RecvPacketParser;

public class Leitor {
    public enum BluetoothEstado {LIGADO, DESLIGADO, NAO_COMPATIVEL;}

    public static final String ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE;
    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    private List<BluetoothDevice> listaDispositivo = new ArrayList<>();
    protected BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private boolean mReceiverStarter;
    private UUID mUuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    protected R900RecvPacketParser mPacketParser = new R900RecvPacketParser();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mArrTag;
    public static final int MSG_SOUND_RX = 40;
    private String mSelTag;
    private BluetoothDevice dispositivo;
    protected boolean mConnected;
    protected Handler mHandler;
    public static final int MSG_BT_DATA_RECV = 10;
    private FileOutputStream mDbgOutStream;
    protected ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    protected ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private OnBtEventListener mBtEventListener;
    protected BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
    private List<Patrimonio> listaPatrimonio ;
    private Set<Patrimonio> setPatrimonio = new HashSet<Patrimonio>();

    public void setSelTag(String mSelTag) {
        this.mSelTag = mSelTag;
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDispositivo() {
        return dispositivo;
    }

    public void setDispositivo(BluetoothDevice dispositivo) {
        this.dispositivo = dispositivo;
    }

    public List<Patrimonio> getListaPatrimonio() {
        return listaPatrimonio = new ArrayList<Patrimonio>(setPatrimonio);
    }

    public List<BluetoothDevice> getListaDispositivo() {
        return listaDispositivo;
    }

    public BluetoothEstado getEstado() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return BluetoothEstado.NAO_COMPATIVEL;
        } else {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                return BluetoothEstado.DESLIGADO;
            }
            return BluetoothEstado.LIGADO;
        }
    }

    public Leitor(Activity activity, Handler handler, OnBtEventListener listener) {
        this.mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mHandler = handler;
        this.mBtEventListener = listener;

        registrarBroadcast();
    }

    //region buscarBluetooth: RETORNA TODOS DISPOSITIVOS BLUETOOTH
    public void buscarBluetooth() {
        listaDispositivo.clear();

        if (getEstado() == BluetoothEstado.LIGADO) {
            dispositivosPareados();
            dispositivosConectados();
        }
    }
    ///endregion

    //region dispositivosPareados: RETORNA OS DISPOSITIVOS PAREADOS COM O APARELHO
    private void dispositivosPareados() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesList = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevicesList.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevicesList) {
                listaDispositivo.add(device);
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region dispositivosConectados: RETORNA TODOS DISPOSITIVOS BLUETOOTH CONECTADOS POR PERTO
    private void dispositivosConectados() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
    //endregion

    //region pararBusca: PARA DE PROCURAR POR DISPOSITIVOS BLUETOOTH
    public void pararBusca() {
        if (mReceiverStarter) {
            activity.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mReceiverStarter = false;
        }

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Conectar
    public void conectar(String address) {
        conectar(mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address));
    }

    public void conectar(BluetoothDevice dispositivo) {
        try {
            this.dispositivo = dispositivo;
            disconnect();
            mConnectThread = new ConnectThread();
            mConnectThread.start();
            mConnected = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            mConnected = false;
        }

    }
    //endregion

    //region disconnect: RESPONSÁVEL POR FINALIZAR A CONEXÃO
    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.stop();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        mConnectThread = null;

        try {
            if (mConnectedThread != null) {
                mConnectedThread.cancel();
                mConnectedThread.stop();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    //endregion

    //region finalize: RESPONSÁVEL POR FINALIZAR A DESCOBERTA DE DISPOSITIVOS
    protected void finalize() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        disconnect();

        if (mDbgOutStream != null) {
            try {
                mDbgOutStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (mReceiverStarter)
            activity.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    //endregion

    //region BroadcastReceiver
    private void registrarBroadcast() {
        // Registro os Broadcast necessarios para a busca de dispositivos
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ILeitor.ACTION_FOUND);
        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(ILeitor.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(ILeitor.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        activity.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        activity.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
        activity.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
        mReceiverStarter = true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.compareTo(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND) == 0) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                //se a lista já tiver esse dispositivo eu retorno para o proximo
                //isso permite que sejá mostrado somente uma vez meu dispositivo
                //problema muito comum em exemplos
                if (listaDispositivo.contains(device)) {
                    return;
                }

                listaDispositivo.add(device);
            }
        }
    };
    //endregion

    //region Thread de Conexão
    // ------------- For Manage bluetooth
    protected class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private boolean mInitOk;

        public ConnectedThread() {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            mPacketParser.reset();

            try {
                tmpIn = mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                mInitOk = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                mInitOk = false;
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public boolean isInitOk() {
            return mInitOk;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while (mInitOk) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    if (mDbgOutStream != null)
                        mDbgOutStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes);

                    mPacketParser.pushPacket(buffer, bytes);

                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_BT_DATA_RECV);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }

    }

    protected class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        public ConnectThread() {
            if (dispositivo != null) {
                try {
                    mBluetoothSocket = dispositivo.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUuid);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                try {
                    mBluetoothSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException connectException) {
                    try {
                        mBluetoothSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    }

                    mConnectThread = null;
                    return;
                }

                // manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
                mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread();
                if (mConnectedThread.isInitOk()) {
                    mConnectedThread.start();

                    if (mBtEventListener != null)
                        mBtEventListener.onBtConnected(dispositivo);
                }
            } else {

            }

            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    protected void atualizarListaTag(final String param) {
        Patrimonio patrimonio;

        Database db = new Database(activity.getApplicationContext());

        if (param == null || param.length() <= 4)
            return;

        final String tagRFId = param.substring(0, param.length() - 4);

        patrimonio = db.buscarPatrimonioTag(tagRFId);
        if (patrimonio == null)
            patrimonio = new Patrimonio();

        patrimonio.setTagRFID(tagRFId);

        setPatrimonio.add(patrimonio);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A classe [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20E%3E%29) tem um construtor que aceita uma *Collection*, use-o para construir a List:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(oSeuSet);
```

Comment: Ramaral, fiz como você indicou, mas mesmo assim está inserindo duplicado. Saberia me dizer onde estou errando? Alterei o primeiro post com o código

Comment: O HashSet não pode ter objectos duplicados. A questão está em saber quando dois *Patrimonio* são iguais*. O HashSet usa o método `equals()` da classe que contêm para fazer essa comparação. Para que essa verificação funcione, a classe *Patrimonio* terá de fazer o *override* dos métodos `equals()` e `hashCode()`, ai você definirá os requisitos para 2 *Patrimonio* serem iguais.

Comment: Maravilha! Deu certo

Answer (score 7):

Utilize o método List.addAll(). Assim:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>;
list.addAll(set);
```

O método addAll aceita uma Collection e todo Set é uma Collection.